# Issue With Proxy Authentication in Application Server for oauth2-microsoft

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, http-proxy

The authentication code is sent back to my application after user logs in.
Then I am getting **stuck while I request for the Access Token**. i.e,

```
$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [ 'code' => $_GET['code'] ]);
```

It takes roughly 30 seconds and then returns the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error creating resource:
> [message] fopen([https://login.microsoftonline.com/[application](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Bapplication)
> id]/oauth2/v2.0/token): failed to open stream: A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond. [file]
> ..\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php [line] 326
> in ..\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php:254 Stack
> trace: #0
> ..\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php(337):
> GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createResource(Object(Closure)) #1
> ..\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php(53):
> GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->createStream(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
> Array) #2 C:\Apac in
> ..\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\StreamHandler.php on line 67

I am using the below code as provider:

```
$provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft([
'clientId' => 'my clientId',
'clientSecret' => 'my clientSecret',
'redirectUri' => 'my redirectUri',

'urlAuthorize'              => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app id]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
'urlAccessToken'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[app id]/oauth2/v2.0/token',
'urlResourceOwnerDetails'   => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',

'response_mode' => 'form_post',
'response_type' => 'id_token'
]);
```

And in Microsoft.php public `$defaultScopes = ['openid profile'];`

My assumption was that it is happening because of the proxy. So I added the below code in the same page from where I am requesting for the token.

```
stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'tcp://IP:port', 'header'=>'Proxy-Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('Username:Password')]]);
```

**For validating the internet connection I tried this proxy for** *scraping* **HTML source code of any random websites and it worked.**

Could you help me on how to set the proxy for oauth2-microsoft? Or am I getting this error because of any other reasons I failed to see?